# Passing Data Between Table Views using Structs and Arrays (Swift : Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a code beginner, actually I've joined this world a few weeks ago. 
I'm trying to build up my first app for Ios by using Xcode and Swift. 
I want to create different table views and passing data between these tables.

Now, I made up the code, but I keep getting an "Expected Declaration" error. I really don't understand how to fix it. Can someone please help me? 
Thanks.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Tot_Forum
//
//  Created by Fausto Saltetti on 18/07/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Fausto Saltetti. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FirtTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var FirstTableArray = [String]()

var SecondArray = [SecondTable]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FirstTableArray = ["Focus on learning", "Participate and network", "Access and build knowledge", "Assess, reflect, evaluate", "Inspire and generate ideas", "Problem solve and plan", "Map ideas and relationships"]

    SecondArray =
        [SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["After Action Review","Audience Response Systems","Blogs","Case Studies", "Discussion Forums UPDATE","Jigsaw","Peer Assist", "Podcasting","Presentations", "Role Play", "Screencasting", "Social Networking", "Sociometrics"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["After Action Review","Audience Response Systems","Blogs","Case Studies", "Discussion Forums UPDATE","Jigsaw","Peer Assist", "Podcasting","Presentations", "Role Play", "Screencasting", "Social Networking", "Sociometrics"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["After Action Review","Audience Response Systems","Blogs","Case Studies", "Discussion Forums UPDATE","Jigsaw","Peer Assist", "Podcasting","Presentations", "Role Play", "Screencasting", "Social Networking", "Sociometrics"])]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
    return FirstTableArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    Cell.textLabel?.text = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]

    return Cell

     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController

        var SecondTableArrayTwo : SecondTable

        SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]

        DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle
        }

}   **//Error here: !Expected declaration**
```

Comment: closing brace "}" is missing for your class

Answer (score 1):

mistake here is your `prepareForSegue` function inside of a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

they should be in the global scope

> var SecondTableArrayTwo : SecondTable? should be unwrapped or optional with its init.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    Cell.textLabel?.text = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]
    return Cell
}  

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        var SecondTableArrayTwo : SecondTable?
        SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]
        DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo!.SecondTitle
}
```

Comment: can I ask to help me a little more by writing the correct code? Or is the one you typed, I've copied and past but it shows me the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the error you are getting, "Expected Declaration" error is for the missing brace "}" of your class.

Solving this error will give you another warning because code written after a return statement never get executed. You have written prepareForSegue function after the return statement.

Now the main issue, prepareForSegue must be in global scope as
@Özgür Ersil mentioned in his answer. Thus add a closing brace for your class. Remove the prepareForSegue function from the cellForRowAtIndexPath function and write it in global scope inside your class.

Hope this will help you :)