# Table data Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a code beginner. For my first app I tried to wrap up a code that let me show different data in different table.

I don't understand why Xcode keeps notify me this error: EXPECTED DECLARATION. Can some one help me to fix this problem.

Thank you so much.

```
 //
//  ViewController.swift
//  Tot_Forum
//
//  Created by Fausto Saltetti on 18/07/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Fausto Saltetti. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FirtTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var FirstTableArray = [String]()

var SecondArray = [SecondTable]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FirstTableArray = ["Focus on learning", "Participate and network", "Access and build knowledge", "Assess, reflect, evaluate", "Inspire and generate ideas", "Problem solve and plan", "Map ideas and relationships"]

    SecondArray =
        [SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["After Action Review","Audience Response Systems","Blogs","Case Studies", "Discussion Forums UPDATE","Jigsaw","Peer Assist", "Podcasting","Presentations", "Role Play", "Screencasting", "Social Networking", "Sociometrics"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["After Action Review","Audience Response Systems","Blogs","Case Studies", "Discussion Forums UPDATE","Jigsaw","Peer Assist", "Podcasting","Presentations", "Role Play", "Screencasting", "Social Networking", "Sociometrics"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["After Action Review","Audience Response Systems","Blogs","Case Studies", "Discussion Forums UPDATE","Jigsaw","Peer Assist", "Podcasting","Presentations", "Role Play", "Screencasting", "Social Networking", "Sociometrics"])]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
    return FirstTableArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    Cell.textLabel?.text = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]
    return Cell
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!    SecondTableViewController
    var SecondTableArrayTwo : SecondTable?
    SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]
    DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo!.SecondTitle

}  // EXPECTED DECLARATION
```

Comment: Have you triple-checked that *all* parentheses match properly? – Did you read this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431522/passing-data-between-table-views-using-structs-and-arrays-swift-xcode#comment64268937_38431522 to your previous question?

Answer (score 2):

If that code is all you have in that file then you are missing the last brace, the one that closes the class. Just add `}` to the end.

I little formatting would help. In Xcode, you can select all with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> for indentation. That would format the code for you and it would be easier to see where you are missing a brace.